# How to regularly merge a GIT repo A into repo B, and keep the merge conflicts to the minimum despite features differences?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, repository, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a base repo A, with most of my colleagues working on it.
For a customer, we had some special features, so we copied and created repo B, and added a few custom features.

Now, we would like to keep repo B updated with regular updates from base repo A, as most of the develop happens there. Nevertheless I keep facing merge conflict issues, and the same I solved the day before.

How would you do ? Right now i have:

```bash
$ git checkout repo_B/develop
$ git fetch repo_A develop
$ git merge FETCH_HEAD --allow-unrelated-histories
BOOM many merge conflicts, even if i just solved the same merge conflicts yesterday.
```

I set the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag for `git merge`, otherwise this is blocking.
I guess the conflicts are caused by the unrelated git histories? I have tried different merge strategies, but without success.
I thought about explicitly set my last merge resolution as common ancestor, but haven't found how to do that.